# Tableau - Multiple Line Graphs Day by Day

Tags: charts, tableau-api

I would like to create a dashboard showing Level Funnel for the users with respect to their register date on the same chart.

My data is like the following:

[image]

And from that data, I would like to create the graph like below:

[image]

But in tableau I couldn't manage to combine those graphs below, which are separated day by day:

[image]

I tried to follow this steps, http://downloads.tableausoftware.com/quickstart/feature-guides/combo_charts.pdf however I couldn't find 'Customize Marks' button in the menu.

That would be great if you can help me on how to combine these graphs into one graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drag the DAY(Date) field from the row shelf to the color shelf

One way to think about it: When you have the DAY(DATE) field on the row shelf, and you've configured it to present as a *discrete* field, you are telling Tableau to "make a row for each day". When you move that field to the color shelf, you are instead telling Tableau to make a color for each day. The same mental substitution works for *discrete* fields on most of the other shelves, like columns, shapes, pages -- i.e. make a page for each day.